# Retrieving sharepoint list items using linq

Tags: linq, sharepoint-2010, datatable

How can I retrieve all items from SharePoint 2010 list and store in a datatable using LINQ query?

Comment: If you want to get _all_ items, why do you need a LINQ query?

Answer (score 0):

SPList yourlist = yourweb.Lists["YourListName"];
SPListItemCollection items = yourList.Items;

The above would give you all the items as a collection then you would only need to iterate and insert into your database. As stated by Rawling, you really dont need a linq query.

regards,
KS